# Having a div/0 error in excel 2007 return a 0 with in a large formula

Tags: excel, divide-by-zero

I apologize if this is not considered real programming since it is in Excel but I need help and this is the most helpful place I know!

Alright so I have a very large if formula in excel:

```
=IF(AND(($EZ16+LF$1139)>$B$1145,($EZ16+LF$1139)<$B$1146),IF(OR(AND($FB16<LF$1141,$FB16>LF$1142),AND($FE16<LF$1141,$FE16>LF$1142),AND($FH16<LF$1141,$FH16>LF$1142),AND($FK16<LF$1141,$FK16>LF$1142),AND($FN16<LF$1141,$FN16>LF$1142),AND($FQ16<LF$1141,$FQ16>LF$1142),AND($FT16<LF$1141,$FT16>LF$1142),AND($FW16<LF$1141,$FW16>LF$1142),AND($FZ16<LF$1141,$FZ16>LF$1142),AND($GC16<LF$1141,$GC16>LF$1142),AND($GF16<LF$1141,$GF16>LF$1142)),FALSE,(EU16/EI16-1)),FALSE)
```

What can I do to it so that if it returns a div/0 error it will pass a value of 0 instead of the `#DIV/0!` error?

Would it be something like:

```
=IF(ISERROR(A1/B1),0,A1/B1)
```

If so how can I  add that to my current formula and not break it? Would it be:

```
=IF(ISERROR(IF(AND(($EZ16+LF$1139)>$B$1145,($EZ16+LF$1139)<$B$1146),IF(OR(AND($FB16<LF$1141,$FB16>LF$1142),AND($FE16<LF$1141,$FE16>LF$1142),AND($FH16<LF$1141,$FH16>LF$1142),AND($FK16<LF$1141,$FK16>LF$1142),AND($FN16<LF$1141,$FN16>LF$1142),AND($FQ16<LF$1141,$FQ16>LF$1142),AND($FT16<LF$1141,$FT16>LF$1142),AND($FW16<LF$1141,$FW16>LF$1142),AND($FZ16<LF$1141,$FZ16>LF$1142),AND($GC16<LF$1141,$GC16>LF$1142),AND($GF16<LF$1141,$GF16>LF$1142)),FALSE,(EU16/EI16-1)),FALSE))**),0,IF**(AND(($EZ16+LF$1139)>$B$1145,($EZ16+LF$1139)<$B$1146),IF(OR(AND($FB16<LF$1141,$FB16>LF$1142),AND($FE16<LF$1141,$FE16>LF$1142),AND($FH16<LF$1141,$FH16>LF$1142),AND($FK16<LF$1141,$FK16>LF$1142),AND($FN16<LF$1141,$FN16>LF$1142),AND($FQ16<LF$1141,$FQ16>LF$1142),AND($FT16<LF$1141,$FT16>LF$1142),AND($FW16<LF$1141,$FW16>LF$1142),AND($FZ16<LF$1141,$FZ16>LF$1142),AND($GC16<LF$1141,$GC16>LF$1142),AND($GF16<LF$1141,$GF16>LF$1142)),FALSE,(EU16/EI16-1)),FALSE))
```

Thank you for the help!

EDIT:
Tim a tried your suggestion:

```
=IF(AND(($EZ16+LF$1139)>$B$1145,($EZ16+LF$1139)<$B$1146),IF(OR(AND($FB16<LF$1141,$FB16>LF$1142),AND($FE16<LF$1141,$FE16>LF$1142),AND($FH16<LF$1141,$FH16>LF$1142),AND($FK16<LF$1141,$FK16>LF$1142),AND($FN16<LF$1141,$FN16>LF$1142),AND($FQ16<LF$1141,$FQ16>LF$1142),AND($FT16<LF$1141,$FT16>LF$1142),AND($FW16<LF$1141,$FW16>LF$1142),AND($FZ16<LF$1141,$FZ16>LF$1142),AND($GC16<LF$1141,$GC16>LF$1142),AND($GF16<LF$1141,$GF16>LF$1142)),FALSE,IF(EI16=1,0,EU16/EI16-1)),FALSE)
```

Still getting a `#DIV/0` error, any idea why?

Comment: This doesn't look quite like valid Excel syntax. What are the `LF` codes?

Comment: LF$1139 has a number in it and no formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=IsError(100/0)` will return `TRUE`, so make the conditional before to output 0, `=IF(IsError(*),0,...)`

Answer (score 4):

Excel 2007 has a new IFERROR function that you can use like

```
=IFERROR(MyLongFormula,0)
```

Comment: This has the added advantage that the formula is entered only once.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend duplicating the whole formula like that: a complicated formula just got twice as complicated.

Since the division only happens in one place, I'd recommend putting the check there. This:

```
...(EU16/EI16-1)...
```

becomes this:

```
...IF(EI16=1, 0, EU16/EI16-1)...
```